# How to reset page number in Django ListView

Tags: django

How to reset page number in Django ListView.

There is a view with filter form, results are paginated.

For example:
First request returns 50 pages, we come to 40 page. Then we change filter, and result is just 10 pages. In the url we have page number 40. And we get 404 page, because result just 10 pages.

Seems I must redirect to the first page while 'POST'. How to make it in ListView

Comment: Tutorial of Django is your friend :) [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view). If page is out of range, deliver last page of results. You can update this code to return to the first page, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except (PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage):
        # If page is not an integer or out of range, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)

    return render(request, 'list.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```